# Google mock internal segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, googlemock

I am trying to use GoogleMock to do UnitTest, meanwhile switching to fake as well.

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <iostream>

using ::testing::Matcher;

class Fake {
public:
    void test(int, float) {}
};

class MockTest {
public:
    MockTest() :
        fake(new Fake()) {
    }

    MOCK_METHOD2(func, void(int, float));
    MOCK_METHOD2(func, void(char*, int));

    void delegate() {
        ON_CALL(*this, func(Matcher<int>(), 
                            Matcher<float>()))
        .WillByDefault([this](int val1, float val2) {
            fake->test(val1, val2);
        });
    }

private:
    Fake *fake;
};

int main() {
    MockTest *test = new MockTest();
    test->delegate();
    test->func(1, 5.6);
}
```

I try to hit fake object everytime func(int, float) is called. It compiles well, but met a segfault. The error message of valgrind shows:

```
[ethan@ethan test]$ valgrind ./gmock_test 
==119183== Invalid read of size 8
==119183==    at 0x10DD74: MatchAndExplain (gmock-matchers.h:292)
==119183==    by 0x10DD74: Matches (gmock-matchers.h:298)
==119183==    by 0x10DD74: Matches<std::tuple<testing::Matcher<int>, testing::Matcher<float> >, std::tuple<int, float> > (gmock-matchers.h:908)
==119183==    by 0x10DD74: Matches<std::tuple<testing::Matcher<int>, testing::Matcher<float> >, std::tuple<int, float> > (gmock-matchers.h:907)
==119183==    by 0x10DD74: TupleMatches<std::tuple<testing::Matcher<int>, testing::Matcher<float> >, std::tuple<int, float> > (gmock-matchers.h:976)
==119183==    by 0x10DD74: Matches (gmock-spec-builders.h:340)
==119183==    by 0x10DD74: FindOnCallSpec (gmock-spec-builders.h:1497)
==119183==    by 0x10DD74: testing::internal::FunctionMockerBase<void (int, float)>::DescribeDefaultActionTo(std::tuple<int, float> const&, std::ostream*) const (gmock-spec-builders.h:1650)
==119183==    by 0x10CF94: testing::internal::FunctionMockerBase<void (int, float)>::UntypedDescribeUninterestingCall(void const*, std::ostream*) const (gmock-spec-builders.h:1672)
==119183==    by 0x40550F5: testing::internal::UntypedFunctionMockerBase::UntypedInvokeWith(void*) (in /misc/toolchain-builds/d1ce2497ca66f4a55430c86fd8812027a7e8d5ea.x86_64/lib/libgmock.so)
==119183==    by 0x10CB3E: InvokeWith (gmock-spec-builders.h:1603)
==119183==    by 0x10CB3E: Invoke (gmock-generated-function-mockers.h:121)
==119183==    by 0x10CB3E: MockTest::func(int, float) (test.cc:19)
==119183==    by 0x10C957: main (test.cc:37)
==119183==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Could someone tell me how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Just saying: 1) Avoid pointers if you don't need them (Fake *, MockTest *). 2)  Every new should have a matching delete.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. This is a toy for simplifying the problem -- real implmentation uses smart pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with matchers here

```
ON_CALL(*this, func(Matcher<int>(), 
                            Matcher<float>()))
```

The `::testing::Matcher<T>` default constructors creates null implementations (gtest/gtest-matchers.h):

```
327   // Constructs a null matcher.  Needed for storing Matcher objects in STL
328   // containers.  A default-constructed matcher is not yet initialized.  You
329   // cannot use it until a valid value has been assigned to it.
330   explicit Matcher() {}  // NOLINT
```

You need to use `any` matcher for your purposes:

```
ON_CALL(*this, func(_, _))
```

Or, because you have this function overloaded, use `A/An` matchers:

```
ON_CALL(*this, func(An<int>(), A<float>()))
```

PS.
No real difference between A and An - just English grammar :)